# Why am I getting "Parent directory of file is not writable?"

Tags: android, permissions, directory

I've reviewed numerous posts but still have no answer.  After adding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE then checking that the sd card is writable and mounted, I still get "Parent directory of file is not writable."  I'm using eclipse and the emulator and targeting SdkVersion="7".

How can I write to the sd card?

Example code follows:

```
<uses-premission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    
    .
    .
    .

    checkSDStatus();
    .
    .
    .

    File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Check state of SD card
    String sdState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    Log.d("--- state ---", sdState);

    File dir = new File (sdCardRoot.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
    dir.mkdirs();

    File file = new File(dir, fileName);

    .
    .
    .

    private void checkSDStatus(){
        boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
        boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
            Log.d("-- sd card --", "-- card writable --");
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            Log.d("-- sd card --", "-- card read only --");
        } else {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            Log.d("-- sd card --", "-- card unvailable --");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll answer my question for others.

After adding  to my manifest file several times previously I had nothing to lose so I copied another version of it and added it to the manifest below the existing permission.

The permissions appeared identical to the eye but I deleted my old one and used the new I had copied in.

I reran the app and it worked!!!  Perhaps there was a bug on the disk, the manifest file wasn't getting read for some reason, or whatever - at least it now works!

If anyone knows why I'd sure like to hear the reason for this problem!